# from a TableViewCell Inside a TableViewCell go to a viewcontroller

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, swift5, xcode12

Im triying to go from a table view cell inside a tableviewcell go to other viewcontroller when is tapped.
when i'm implementing

```
vc?.navigationController?.present(VC!, animated: true),
```

this doesn't work

here is the code that I have used

[image]

Comment: Please post code (ideally, a [mre]), not pictures of code, which aren't copy/pastable, searchable, or able to be read by screen readers.

Answer (score 0):

My guts feeling is that maybe you don't have a navigation controller at the moment, if you tap the cell and nothing happens.

I suggest you can set a break point at line you provided

```
vc?.navigationController?.present(vc!, animated: true)
```

and verify if `navigationController` is `nil`

If that's the case, you need to create a `navigationController` either via storyboard or via code before you use it push another vc into `navigationController` stack and present it.

Hope this is helpful, cheers!

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer, can you explain me how i can create that Navigation controller,  if I'm using a tableviewcell inside a tableviewcell, I've been trying everything and nothing has work for me

Comment: Hi i've been checking and I found than my Navigation view Controller return a nil,  but i don'y know how to correct that issue

Comment: Check out Sean's video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LbAd2FIlnos) about the navigation controller. The video is very comprehensive and you should be able to start from there, or you can take some courses and see how app is built step by step. Good luck!